# SQL Query to find no of records created per day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table with below details.

```
Id      Name       created_date
-----------------------------------------------
1       ABC   20-AUG-15 07.59.50.765000000 AM
2       ABD   20-AUG-15 08.59.50.765000000 AM
3       ABE   20-AUG-15 09.59.50.765000000 AM
4       ABF   20-AUG-15 06.59.50.765000000 AM
5       BCD   21-AUG-15 07.59.50.765000000 AM
6       BCE   21-AUG-15 08.59.50.765000000 AM.
```

I need the result of no.of Accounts created in one day (SQL Query). It should be generic.

Output:

```
 CountPerDay    created_date
------------------------------------------------
   4         20-AUG-15 07.59.50.765000000 AM
   2         20-AUG-15 08.59.50.765000000 AM
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a simple `group by` query:

```
select trunc(created_date), count(*) as num_created
from the_table
group by trunc(created_date);
```

The `trunc()` is necessary because in Oracle a `DATE` column contains a time part as well (or if your `created_date` is in fact a `timestamp` not a `date`).

Comment: When one day has no record means, it didn't show that day with count as zero. How can we list out that record?